# Photo and Video recovery?

Tags: data-corruption

i have a bunch of sentimental photos and videos (32ish GB) that were corrupted and was wondering if anyone had any idea how to recover data. what software should I use? Do I do it manually? just anything to help me get this back, please! They are .jpg, .png, and .mp4 files.

Comment: recover from where and what?

Comment: @ths .jpg, .png, .mp4 files from an laptop 500g hard drive. they are able to be copied and now i also have them on an external hard drive as well as my PC

Comment: If they're corrupted on their primary storage & also your recovery attempt, then you need to go to your backup.

Comment: @Tetsujin the backup i dont have.. damn. okay

Comment: The usual 'go-to' is PhotoRec, but it only reads some disk formats & used to be better before the days of SSD [& especially encrypted SSD] when the actual file layout on disk was much more predictable. You could try a data recovery company - but they make no guarantees. Have a look at some of the 'Related' links in the right sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but the most likely scenario here is that your files are toast. A specialist data recovery company *might* be able to do something with the original drive and maybe get some of them back - but expect to pay hundreds to thousands of (US) dollars for them even to look at it, with no guarantee of success. If you are even considering going down this route, remove all power from the drive immediately and don't plug it in again - anything you do now will only make it harder to recover the data.